# Removing last word from specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to remove the last specific word from each sentence within some classes. Example:

```
<p class="remove">Active speakers hire</p>
<p class="remove">Passive speakers hire</p>
```

I want to remove the word "hire" from every paragraph that has the "remove" class attached to it. I understand that this can be done individually using the following code:

```
var str = "Active speakers hire";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");

str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
```

But how to do that in the external jquery file based on the classes? I don't want to type in the js code individually for each paragraph. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this using [`text-function`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) like:

```js
$('.remove').text(function(i, txt) {
  return txt.substring(0, txt.lastIndexOf(" "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="remove">Active speakers hire</p>
<p class="remove">Passive speakers hire</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$(".remove").each(function() {
    var str = this.html()
    var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
    this.html(str.substring(0, lastIndex));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery necessary:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

[].forEach.call(items, item => {
 var newText = item.innerHTML.split(' ');
 newText.pop();
 item.innerHTML = newText.join(' ');
});
```

```html
<p class="remove">Active speakers hire</p>
<p class="remove">Passive speakers hire</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution below won't work in IE due to [NodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), but it has no dependencies.

```
const process = node => {
    let str = node.innerHTML
    node.innerHTML = str.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ')
}

document.querySelectorAll('.remove').forEach(process)
```

To make it work in IE you'll have to iterate nodelist in other way, but I think it's not a problem.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxuxtaf2/10/)